# Failed conversion from promise syntax for jQuery ajax function to try/catch/finally and async/await?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, async-await, es6-promise

The jQuery code below works well.

```
// Make request.
$.ajax(settings)
.done(function(result) {
    requestDidSucced(result);
})
.fail(function(result) {
    requestDidFail(result);
})
.always(function(result) {
    requestDidFinish(result);
});
```

However, converting this code to use `try/catch/finally` and `async/await` fails because the `finally` block doesn't have access to the result of `$.ajax()`.

In particular, if we define `result` outside the `try` block, is it safe to assume `result` gets a value with the `finally` block like it did with the `always` block?

```
// Make request.
try {
    let result = await $.ajax(settings);
    requestDidSucceed(resultBox, result);
} catch (result) {
    requestDidFail(result);
} finally {
    requestDidFinish(result); // This fails because `request` is not available.
}
```

Is it possible for the `finally` block to access the result of the AJAX query?

Comment: Can't you just declare result outside of the try block and assign it with the await ?

Comment: @Woody what happens to `result` if there's an error thrown in `$.ajax`? Is `requestDidFinish` guaranteed to get a value for `result`?

Comment: no if there was an error result would be undefined.

Comment: @Woody thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `result` outside of the `try` block:

```
// Make request.
let result;
try {
    result = await $.ajax(settings);
    requestDidSucceed(resultBox, result);
} catch (error) {
    requestDidFail(error);
} finally {
    requestDidFinish(result);
}
```

However, you should be careful how you arrange this. E.g. the `catch` clause will also be invoked if `requestDidSucceed` throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! What do you mean by careful? Won't `requestDidFinish` be guaranteed to finish last?

Comment: Also what happens to `result` if `$.ajax` throws an error? Is `requestDidFinish` guaranteed to get a value for `result`?

Comment: *"Won't requestDidFinish be guaranteed to finish last?"* Yes, but as I said `requestDidFail` will be called if either `$.ajax` or `requestDidSucceed` fails. *"Also what happens to result if $.ajax throws an error? Is requestDidFinish guaranteed to get a value for result?"* `result` would be `undefined`. What do you want to pass if `$.ajax` throws?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The goal is to reproduce the `.always` functionality as close as possible because we want to move away from the old promise syntax.